# best statistical approach to study the time evolution of clustering in a data set

Tags: clustering, algorithms, kalman-filter, intraclass-correlation, discrete-time

I am using a **stochastic method** for the clustering of a data set. The number of clusters that this approach returns, can differ in each iteration. On the other hand, I would like to study the evolution of clustering at different snapshot of the data. In the following plot, I ran this clustering method for $N$ times in one snap shot and then I plotted the probability of two data points being clustered in the same group in a given time. [image]

**My question:**

What is the best statistical approach to compare the evolution of this two-dimensional matrix in terms of, *for instance*, the size of blocks which are appeared in this matrix or the shape of the whole matrix in general?